# AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver and Service not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm refactoring some code so that my app will pull data from a website once a day at a given time. From my research, it seems like `AlarmManager` is the most appropriate approach.

The tutorial I have been following is: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-downloading-data-with-services/

So far, `AlarmManager` and the `BroadcastReceiver` seem to be working, however the `Service` never seems to start (ie. `onStartCommand` doesn't seem to be called)

Here are the important snippets of the code I have so far:

**MyActivity.java**

```java
private void setRecurringAlarm(Context context) {
    Calendar updateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    updateTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    updateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    updateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    Intent downloader = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // should be AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY (but changed to 15min for testing)
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, updateTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent); 
    Log.d("MyActivity", "Set alarmManager.setRepeating to: " + updateTime.getTime().toLocaleString());
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```java
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(dailyUpdater);
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive");
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```java
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("MyService", "About to execute MyTask");
        new MyTask().execute();
        return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, boolean> {
        @Override
        protected boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.d("MyService - MyTask", "Calling doInBackground within MyTask");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<application ...>
    ...
    <service android:name="MyService"></service>
    <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
</application>
```

When I trigger the `setRecurringAlarm` in `MyActivity` the log prints as expected, similarly, every 15min the log from `AlarmReceiver` appears. However, I never see the log from `MyService` :(

Example of what I see in the logs:

```
DEBUG/MyActivity(688): Set alarmManager.setRepeating to: Jan 29, 2012 8:30:06 PM
DEBUG/AlarmReceiver(688): Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive
DEBUG/AlarmReceiver(688): Called context.startService from AlarmReceiver.onReceive
```

Can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong - my understanding from the [Android Dev Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) is that in `AlarmReceiver` when I call `context.startService(dailyUpdater)` that should in turn call `onStartCommand` in `MyService`, though that doesn't seem to be the case!

What am I doing wrong that is causing `MyService` to not start at all?

Comment: You're also running into a non-obvious wakelock behavior of starting services in response to alarms.  There are some details and recommendations in the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852309/does-alarmmanager-require-the-pendingintent-to-be-of-type-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Figured it out!

**MyService** should be extending **IntentService** instead of **Service**!

With this change, it also means that instead of overriding `onStartCommand` should be overriding `onHandleIntent` instead (see docs on [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html))

So **MyService** now looks like this:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("MyServiceName");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("MyService", "About to execute MyTask");
        new MyTask().execute();
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, boolean> {
        @Override
        protected boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Log.d("MyService - MyTask", "Calling doInBackground within MyTask");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: From the docs, the default implementation of `onBind` returns `null` so no need to override it.

More information about extending `IntentService`: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#ExtendingIntentService

Comment: +1 Thanks! The "Service" class works just fine on Android 4.x devices but I couldn't workout why it was not working on Android 2.x devices. When changing to "IntentService" it worked like a charm. Lessons learned!

Answer (score 0):

You could get AlarmManager to run the Service straight away rather than going through a BroadcastReceiver, if you change your intent like this:

```
//Change the intent
Intent downloader = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

//Change to getService()
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, downloader, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

This may solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried this before (though without the downloader.addFlags) and it didn't work - will try with addFlags and see if it helps! Just wondering, why does 'BroadcastReceiver' exist if you can just run the Service directly?

Comment: Tried this change - didn't work :( also tried changing `context` to `this` as suggested by kumar... no luck either!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(context, MyService.class);`

use

`Intent dailyUpdater = new Intent(this, MyService.class);`

Other suggestion is to start service directly from alarm rather than sending a broadcast and starting the service in broadcast receiver.

Comment: have you tried ur code without downloader.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: hi kumar, yes I believe I did try it without `addFlags` as well, didn't work either.