# how to make service running even if activity closed?

Tags: android

I have an application that communicates with socket.

I want bind **socket service** to the communication activity. But if the **activity closed**, the **service destoryed**.

How can I keep the socket service running whatever the activity is open or closed?

If I started notification to my application when the activity stopped, the service is running or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can start your Service according to your requirement.

Please go through http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: use the startService method with my app?I need exchange data from service to the activity.I think that Broadcast Receiver could do that. Whether my app was killed by system when memory is low?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Broadcast Receiver, Alarm Manager and Service for this functionality,

Refer below post

[AlarmManager, BroadcastReceiver and Service not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053249/alarmmanager-broadcastreceiver-and-service-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can start service in Another process than your application by android:process tag.