# Does AlarmManager require the PendingIntent to be of Type BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, intentservice

The documentation for [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) seems to imply (but does not outright explicitly require) that the [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) you pass in to any of the `set()` methods should be of the type [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), but I tested passing in other component types (like an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)) and it seemed to work fine.

Is it safe to use non-[BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) Intents with [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)?

Comment: as per the documentation that you linked for `PendingIntent` you can see that it says you can use `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service`

Comment: I see that, but I don't see any `AlarmManager` specific wording inside `PendingIntent`. I want to know if `AlarmManager` is doing the right thing with the `PendingIntent` I pass in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and it has always worked, but I suspect not in the way that you're thinking.  You can use any PendingIntent with an alarm; this could indeed be an activity or service PendingIntent.  If it's a service PendingIntent, then the OS will call startService() for you when the alarm fires.  The hidden catch is about the behavior of *wakeup* alarms.

When any alarm fires, the OS holds a wakelock on the sender's behalf for as long as it takes to deliver the PendingIntent, at which point the wakelock is released and the device is allowed to go back to sleep.  The exact meaning of "as long as it takes to deliver" depends on which kind of PendingIntent is being used.

Broadcast delivery is essentially treated as synchronous: the wakelock is held by the Alarm Manager until the recipient's onReceive() callback returns.  This gives you a hard guarantee that whatever processing you want to do in onReceive() is guaranteed to proceed without the device sleeping.

However, activity and service PendingIntent delivery does not wait for the recipient in the same way.  With those kinds of alarm PendingIntents, the device remains awake long enough to *begin* the process of starting the target activity or service, but then it can (and does) go back to sleep immediately after that launch has begun, before the target code actually has a chance to run.  In practice this means that with a service PendingIntent, even if the alarm is a wakeup alarm, the service will often not actually execute until the device as a whole is woken up normally, e.g. the next time the user turns on the screen manually.

Sometimes this is okay, if your code doesn't actually care that even though the alarm fired at 3am, the service didn't start running until 7am when the alarm clock went off and lit up the phone for an extended period.  More often, though, what apps need to do is use a broadcast alarm, then in their onReceive() -- knowing that the device will sleep as soon as they return -- acquire their *own* wakelock and start up the service under that wakelock, etc.

There is a terrific support library class called WakefulBroadcastReceiver that encapsulates this alarm-wakelock-service dance and makes it both easy and bulletproof; it's https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html.  Use that if you ever want to start a service in response to a wakeup alarm.

Comment: Would the intents be processed when the device wakes up ?

Comment: Yes.  It's exactly the same as if some app had called startService() or startActivity() just as the device was going to sleep.  That doesn't abort the operation; it just doesn't get around to processing the start until something wakes up the device again.

Comment: Thanks - I could not find any docs on this - I would really appreciate a link ;) - you might want to answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086067/when-to-acquire-wakelock-for-an-intent-service